# Codeigniter return single row on numeric columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

so I have a table like below:

```
Day      | 2 | 4 | 6 |8 |10 | 12 | 14 | 16| 
-------------------------------------------
3/12/2014| 0 | 0 | 1 |1 | 1 | 1  | 0  | 1 |
```

and my query is

```
SELECT `14` FROM (`Time_clock`) WHERE `Day` = '03/12/2014'
```

**my query is returning 0, which is correct.**

but i cannot bind and return the result i'm getting `Undefined property: stdClass::$14`

I just want the single row result [0] when I try to do:

```
    $this->db->select($current_hour);
    $this->db->from('Time_clock');
    $this->db->where('Day',$Todays_Date);
    $query = $this->db->get();      
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
            $row = $query->row(); 
            return $row->$current_hour; //error in this line
            }
```

Is it because of my column headers are numeric?

Comment: See normalization, and yes - do not use integers as column identifiers.

Comment: @Strawberry i'm using military time to keep track of the hours in the day so that's why the column headers are numeric i don't see an issue with it.

Comment: @strawberry could you suggest a better way to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column name numeric is definitely a good idea because beginning with numeric value is not a valid identifier thats give your the error as you are trying to get object property like `$row->$current_hour` where `$current_hour` contain the property name and that is numeric and its not valid property name. But still your can get the data by changing your code like following

Add "`" on your select for protecting identifier for mysql as if CI see its a number it think you are passing a default value on your select so it ignore the identifier protection and you will get always the column name as value too

```
    $this->db->select("`$current_hour`");
    $this->db->from('Time_clock');
    $this->db->where('Day', $Todays_Date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row_array(); // get as array 
        return $row[$current_hour]; //user array index instant of object property 
    }
```

I `strongly` recommend add a prefix on your table column ie `hour_2, hour_3, ...`

and use like this  `$this->db->select("hour_$current_hour");`

Answer (score 1):

A better design might look like this...

```
Date       | Hour | Flag
2014-12-03 |  2   |   0
2014-12-03 |  4   |   0
2014-12-03 |  6   |   1
2014-12-03 |  8   |   1
2014-12-03 | 10   |   1
2014-12-03 | 12   |   1
2014-12-03 | 14   |   0
2014-12-03 | 16   |   1
```

...or this...

```
Datetime              |  Flag
2014-12-03 02:00:00   |   0
2014-12-03 04:00:00   |   0
2014-12-03 06:00:00   |   1
2014-12-03 08:00:00   |   1
2014-12-03 10:00:00   |   1
2014-12-03 12:00:00   |   1
2014-12-03 14:00:00   |   0
2014-12-03 16:00:00   |   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return $row->$current_hour;
```

To

```
$value = $row->current_hour;

return $value;
```

That second $ was messing you up.

** And it's case sensitive, so match the column header exactly from the db **

Comment: now im getting: `Undefined property: stdClass::$current_hour`

Comment: @Undermine2k I updated the answer try that and don't forget it's case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
SELECT 14 FROM table_name WHERE date(Day)="'2014/03/02'"
```